# Not able to get correct method for "if" statement and UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uialertaction

I am doing one project like finding quiz answer. It will randomely generate question with 3 option. If answer is correct score will be 1. If answer is not correct score will be decrease. And if score is less than equal to 0 then an UIAlert will display "You loss".

**Problem:**

But unfortunately if I click the correct answer also UIAlert is showing "You loss". And if my answer is correct also my score is not incrementing. This is my `viewcontroller.swift` I declare so if statements also. I don't know still I miss anything wrong.

**Needed in if condition:**

- If answer is correct its should increase by showing `uialert`
- if answer is wrong it should decrease by showing `uialert`
- if score is <= the `uialert` message that show "you loss"
- if score is == 200 `uialert` message that shows"you win"

This only i want to declared in my code .but I tried it's not work for me!

Comment: Now what is your problem ? It's not clear from your question. And may you should do some research on the switch-case statements in swift and replace your if's with that. Also move the code from the if (or if you use switch-case) to separate functions to make your code more readable

Comment: my problem was .i done if statement for my 3 conditions. see my post on "Needed in if condition" .but i am not able get correct statement.its not wroking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your post is not clear about what you need. before consider my answer "Glenn" solution also best. So let me assume with your needs from your  **Needed in if condition** part from your question. I have checked this code with my solution its working well. Here i will give your solution for your problem with some example .You try to Rechange it with your requirements .

```
@IBAction func clickbutton(sender: UIButton)

{

    if sender.tag == matching
 {

    // please initialize before  ( var anyname : string = “”) 

    anyname = “Correct"

      ++score

 } 

    else if score >= 1 

{

    anyname = "Wrong"

    --score


 }

      else if (score <= 0 && sender.tag == correctAnswer)

 {

      anyname = " Correct Nice Try"

      ++score

}

    // initialize var notmatching = 0 before

     else if(score <= 0 || sender.tag == notmatching) 

{

      score = 0
     anyname = “losser"
    print(" oops 0")

}

     else if score == 4 {

     print("winner")

    anyname = “winner”

    score = 0

    ++score

 }
      else 
{


        // you can make another condition or leave it
}



    // here make UIAlert for all condition with their  title name : anything

 }
```

proving answer is not good.so try by your self and let me know.

Comment: 1 question  you said // here to make UIAlert means

Comment: yes there you need to set UIAlert for showing up your score. For every condition to check there is a title called  `name anything`.make that as a title for your alert.

Comment: can I use seperate UIAlert for each condition .it is posiible

Comment: yes its possible only for 1 0r 2 conditions .but in your code you use  3 to 4 conditions.so its will not work in some condition .Not sure but i got error while create separate UIAlert .